# Finding tower location co-ordinates of mobile tower in android

Tags: android, android-2.2-froyo

I just wanted to know the correct way of fetching the tower location in android...
is it possible for us to get the location co-ordinates of the tower  from LAC (Location Area Code ) and CID(Cell ID)??

//This is how i am fetching the CID and LAC

```
GsmCellLocation gsmCellLocation = (GsmCellLocation) telephonyManager.getCellLocation();
gsmCellLocation.getCid();
gsmCellLocation.getLac();
```

Now by following [this way](http://www.anddev.org/poor_mans_gps_-_celltowerid_-_location_area_code_-lookup-t257.html) can i get the location co-ordinates of the tower??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the cid of the cell tower and try to get the location from some location providers.

For example, [The Google Maps GeoLocation API.](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/geolocation/#cell_tower_object)